# Calling `Clear()` on a list initialized with an initial capacity

Tags: c#, list, generic-list

I have a list with a specified initial capacity:

```
private void Foo()
{
    List<double> myList = new List<double>(1024);
    myList.Add(1.0);
    myList.Add(2.0);
    ....

    myList.Clear(); <-- what is the list's 'initial' capacity now?
}
```

What will be `myList`'s capacity after calling `myList.Reset()`? 
Is it 1024?

Comment: Why don't you check yourself with `myList.Capacity`?

Comment: @Soner - you are of course, correct. Somehow `Capacity` slipped my mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwb5h52a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> **Capacity remains unchanged**. To reset the capacity of the List, call the TrimExcess method or set the Capacity property directly. Decreasing the capacity reallocates memory and copies all the elements in the List. Trimming an empty List sets the capacity of the List to the default capacity.

Of course you can confirm this for yourself simply by setting a breakpoint and checking the value of the [`Capacity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y52x03h2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property before and after you call `Clear`.

There is no `Reset` method (unless you're referring to some extension method), but the documentation quoted above indicates you can reset the capacity by calling [`TrimExcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132207%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

```
List<double> myList = new List<double>(1024);
Console.WriteLine(myList.Capacity);
myList.Add(1.0);
myList.Add(2.0);
Console.WriteLine(myList.Capacity);
myList.Clear();
Console.WriteLine(myList.Capacity);
```

Capacity remains unchanged. To reset the capacity of the List, call the TrimExcess method or set the Capacity property directly. Decreasing the capacity reallocates memory and copies all the elements in the List. Trimming an empty List sets the capacity of the List to the default capacity.

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwb5h52a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx